# WP_Query same request, different syntax - one of which does not work

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a WP_Query which works well:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'meta_key'  => 'product_subtype',
'meta_value'=> 'public',
'compare'   => '='      
);
```

but as I want to search for multiple meta_keys, I tried the 'array'-syntax:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'meta_query' => array(                 
                  array(
                    'meta_key'     => 'product_subtype',
                    'meta_value'   => 'public',
                    'compare'      => '='
                      ),
                    ),                  
);
```

but it does not work - it gives me all the posts with 'post_type' = 'product'  - although it is the very same request. I don't know why. Can somebody point out the error?

I execute the query in the following way (like it is told in all the tutorials I found)

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

like I said, the first way works and I get only products with "product_subtype = public" the second one ignores the meta query array.
But why?

Comment: change `meta_key` to `key` and `meta_value` to `value` and then try again.

Comment: that was it - thank you a lot - in germany there is a saying: sometimes you don't see the forest because of the many trees :D - works now ;)

Comment: Glad I managed to help you. You can accept my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, You are using `WP_Query` wrongly. There is not big mistake but if you go through [Codex for WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), You will notice that `meta_query` array used without `meta_` prefix.

So if you remove `meta_` prefix from your query, it will work as expected.