# Woocommerce - List product by using specific attributes

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make a custom query to fetch product that have "League = NCAA" as showing in the picture. I have total 74 **leagues of ncaa** .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQDAL.png

Right now my query is like this but it shows nothing.

```
<ul class="products grid ncaa">
        <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'meta_key' => 'league',
        'meta_value' => 'ncaa',
        'posts_per_page' => 12

        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
         woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' );
    }

?>
      </ul>
```

After searching from the database for keyword 'NCAA' its shows me this table, but I don't know how to fetch from here:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjK17.png

After viewing the table I tried to make this query and it shows me single product only at front end, but i want to display all **ncaa** attribute containing products.

```
 <ul class="products grid ncaa">
        <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'meta_key' => '_product_attributes',
        'meta_value' => 'a:2:{s:6:"league";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:6:"League";s:5:"value";s:4:"NCAA";s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:0;s:8:"position";i:0;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;}s:3:"upc";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:3:"UPC";s:5:"value";s:12:"889345125070";s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:0;s:8:"position";i:0;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;}}',
        'posts_per_page' => 12

        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
         woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' );
    }

?>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182918/wp-query-same-request-different-syntax-one-of-which-does-not-work/31183433#31183433)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just did this and it work like a charm:-)

```
 <ul class="products grid ncaa">
                            <?php
                            $args = array(
                                //'meta_compare' => 'LIKE',
                                'post_type'      => 'product',
                                'posts_per_page' => '74',
                                'meta_query'     => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key'     => '_product_attributes',
                                        'value'   => 'ncaa',
                                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                                        'type'    => 'ncaa'
                                    )
                                )
                            );
                            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                                    {
                                        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                                    }
                                endwhile;
                            } else {
                                woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' );
                            }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help:

```
 <ul class="products grid ncaa">
    <?php

$args = array(
    'meta_key'     => '_product_attributes',
    'meta_value'   => '',
    'meta_compare' => '!=',
    'post_type'    => 'product'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        $data = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_product_attributes', true);
        if(in_array('NCAA',$data)){
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
        else{
            //Do Nothing
        }
    endwhile;
} else {
     woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' );
}

?>
</ul>
```

for more reference go to: [Class Reference/WP Query - Custom Field Parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer but it didn't work. It shows me blank page.

Comment: try print_r($data) and see what you are getting within the loop

Comment: try change the if condition from if(in_arrray('NCAA' , $data)) to if(in_array('ncaa', $data)). See if it works for you.