# Filtering WooCommerce Products by $_GET

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

What I need to be able to do is apply a value for an attribute in the URL, so only the products match that attribute are displayed.  I don't want to do any widgets or other visible filters on the page.

For this I presume I would need to use one of the [webhooks](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html), and filtering out all products that are *about* to be displayed.

Can anyone advise which hook will be best in this case and a simple explanation on how the triggered function will return the new array of products?

Thanks in advance!

*NB*: I also want to query a custom attribute, which does not have any terms, just a straight key/value.

**UPDATE 1**
I'm playing with two techniques; one is very reliable, and that's basically to use:

```
if (!$product->attributes || $product->get_attribute( 'testKey' ) != $_GET["testKey"]) {
    //return;
}
```

at the top of **content-product.php**, but of course WooCommerce will still say the original value for found_posts. Certainly not ideal.

I've come across that something like this should work in **functions.php**:

```
function testFilter($meta_query) {
    $meta_query[] = array (
        'key'     => 'testKey',
        'value'   => 'testVal',
        'compare' => '='
    );
    return $meta_query;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'testFilter', 9 );
```

Except it doesn't, returns no results, doesn't matter if I use LIKE, EXISTS etc. Am I using it wrong?

**UPDATE 2**
I'm not going to say this is the answer, as this only seems to look for one value within a group of custom attributes, but [this result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34451252/859930) has helped.

Answer (score -2):

```
add_filter( 'wpv_filter_query', 'wpv_filter_color_attribute' );
function wpv_filter_color_attribute( $query_args) { 
   $tax_query = array();
   $tax_query['taxonomy'] = 'pa_size';
   $tax_query['field'] = 'term_id';
   $tax_query['terms'] = $_GET['pa_size'];
   $query_args['tax_query'] = array($tax_query);
   return $query_args;
 }
```

You should replace "pa_size" with your attribute taxonomy slug, also $_GET['pa_size'] with the right URL parameter.

You can filter products by attributes using above code. I have not tried this. But, this may help you.

Comment: That's not working, and I don't see *wpv_filter_query* listed in the documentation - is this a typho?  Updating Post...

Comment: I don't know very much about this. You may have to use another filter in place of "wpv_filter_query" which is used to filter 'wp_query'  or you have to add priority to filter.